# IIS Reverse Proxy Outbound Rules

Tags: xml, iis, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up of reverse proxy which is already implemented using nginx in Linux. I am using URL redirect ad-on and ARR. What I want to do is when someone hits the

```
www.example.com/product1/
```

its should send the request to

```
product1.example.com:8443.
```

and if someone hits

```
www.example.com/product2/
```

it should send the request to 
`product2.example.com:8449` and so on and so forth. 
The problem I am facing is when the request reaches to `product1.example.com:8443` using  `www.example.com/product1/`  and the content page is opened, whenever I try to access the content of `product1.example.com:8443` using `www.example.com/product1/` it gives me   Error 404.0 - Not Found, Please note that `product1.example.com:8443` and `product2.example.com:8449` are not hosted on IIS. These are on different VMs. I am just using IIS reverse proxy to rewrite URL.
what my understanding is it is any relative path or for that matter, absolute paths as well need to be translated to the new URL structure.

original web,conf file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^product1(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://product1.example.com:8443/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Portainer-reverse-proxy" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^product2(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://product2.example.com:8449/{R:1}" />
</rule>
</rules>
<outboundRules>
<rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
<match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^/(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" value="/{C:1}/{R:1}" />
<conditions>
<add input="{URL}" pattern="^(product1|product2).*" />
</conditions>
</rule>
<preConditions>
<preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
<add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
</preCondition>
</preConditions>
</outboundRules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite url is incorrect, you can try below code:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^product1(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://product1.example.com:8443{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Portainer-reverse-proxy" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^product2(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://product2.example.com:8449{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Best regards,

Sam

Comment: I see you have added http:// in front of `product1.example.com:8443{R:1}` 
I have omitted http because StackOverflow was not allowing to post more than 10 links in the question.Somehow I have added Http in the question again and using just like that in the rules as well. The problem remains the same.

Comment: Remove the "/" after the port in the url, have you tried?